# Optimal short-hand roman numeral generator

Tags: code-golf, roman-numerals

**Goal:**
Write a function that takes a number as input and returns a short-hand roman numeral for that number as output.

**Roman Numeral Symbols:**

```
Symbol  Value
I       1
V       5
X       10
L       50
C       100
D       500
M       1,000
```

For an example of what I mean when I say "short-hand roman numerals", let's consider finding a roman numeral to represent 1983, because that is the year I was born.  One option is to do this the normal way (10 letters):

**1983** = **MCMLXXXIII** = (1000 - 100 + 1000 + 50 + 30 + 3)

The other option is to do it the short-hand way (6 characters):

**1983** = **MXVIIM** = (1000 - (10 + 10) + 1000 + 3)

Do you know what this means?!?!!??  If I was roman I could have saved 4 characters every single time I wrote my birth date!  Woot Woot!!

However, before I get ahead of myself in excitement, I have a question to write, so I should probably define the short-hand roman numeral rules so we are all on the same page:

**Short-Hand Roman Numeral Rules:**

1. Always consider symbols from left to right until there are no more characters to consider.
2. If there are no higher-valued symbols to the right of the current symbol:

   - Add the value of the current symbol to the running total of this roman numeral.
3. If there are higher-valued symbols to the right of the symbol you are considering:

   - Locate the rightmost highest-valued symbol to the right of the current symbol
   - Consider all the characters up to that symbol as one roman numeral
   - Calculate the value of that roman numeral using these steps
   - Subtract the value of that roman numeral from the running total of this roman numeral.
   - Move to the next symbol after the group you just considered
4. Each roman numeral must have at least 1 symbol in it.
5. That's it!  Anything following these rules will be accepted!

**Examples:**

```
IIIIV = (-(1+1+1+1)+5) = 1  //Don't ask me why you'd want to do this!  

VVX = (-(5+5) + 10) = 0  //Who said you couldn't represent 0 with roman numerals?!!?

VVXM = (-(-(5+5) + 10) + 1000) = 1000  //Again...don't ask me why you'd want to do this!

MXIIXMI = (1000-(10-(1+1)+10)+1000+1) = 1983  //Ahhh...such a great year :)
```

**Question Rules:**

1. Make a function that takes a single number as input and returns a roman numeral for that number as output using the above rules.  Calculate the **codeGolfScore** of this function.

   ```
   example input: 2011
   example possible output: MMXI
   another possible output: MMVVIVV     //(2000 + 10 - 4 + 5)
   ```
2. Using your function from rule 1, generate the roman numerals between -1000 (that's right, NEGATIVE one-thousand) and 3000.  Then sum up the character length of these roman numerals to get your **totalCharacterCount**.  Here's some pseudocode to clarify:

   ```
   totalCharacterCount = 0;
   for(currentNumber = -1000; currentNumber <= 3000; currentNumber++){
       totalCharacterCount += getRomanNumeral(currentNumber).length;
   }
   return totalCharacterCount;
   ```
3. **finalScore** = **codeGolfScore** +  **totalCharacterCount**
4. Lowest **finalScore** wins!

Note:  As the totalCharacter count will be in the ten-thousands+, the character-length algorithm should be top priority.  Code-golf scores are just the tie-breaker in case multiple users find the optimal algorithm or algorithms that are close to each other.

Good luck, and have fun at your MMXII celebrations tomorrow night!!!

Comment: Great task! However, could you give an example of how a negative roman shorthand looks like? Does `DDDDM` stand for `-1000`?

Comment: @pimvdb You got it!

Comment: A question regarding the special case zero: Is `""` allowed for zero or do we have to use `VVX` or something equivalent?

Comment: @Howard:  Great question, I hadn't thought of that!  I've added roman numeral rule 4 for which clarifies that case.

Comment: "Locate the rightmost highest-valued symbol to the right of the current symbol" -- which wins, rightmost or highest-valued?  i.e., is `IXV = -(-1 + 10) + 5 = -4` (rightmost wins), or `IXV = -1 + 10 + 5 = 14` (highest-valued wins)?

Comment: @KeithRandall I think it must be latter. Otherwise it would have to read "rightmost _higher_-valued".

Comment: @KeithRandall:  Highest value wins, so `IXV = 14`, and `IXVX =-14+10= -4`.

Comment: Is IDC as well as DIC allowed for 599 (499+100 vs. 500+99)?

Comment: @userunknown: Yep, both are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

### C++, 345 characters of code, 25021 roman numeral digits = 25366

```
int N[]={1,5,10,50,100,500,1000};int V(int s,int L){if(!L)return 0;int K=0,B,m=s%7+1;for(int k=1,b=7;k<L;k++,b*=7){if(s/b%7>=m){K=k;B=b;m=s/b%7;}}return K?V(s/B,L-K)-V(s%B,K):N[s%7]+V(s/7,L-1);}char r[99];char*f(int n){for(int L=1,B=7,i,j;1;L++,B*=7){for(i=0;i<B;i++){if(V(i,L)==n){for(j=0;j<L;j++){r[j]="IVXLCDM"[i%7];i/=7;}r[L]=0;return r;}}}}
```

deobfuscated a bit, with a driver:

```
int N[]={1,5,10,50,100,500,1000};
int V(int s,int L){
  if(!L)return 0;
  int K=0,B,m=s%7+1;
  for (int k=1,b=7;k<L;k++,b*=7) {
    if(s/b%7>=m){K=k;B=b;m=s/b%7;}
  }
  return K ? V(s/B,L-K)-V(s%B,K) : N[s%7]+V(s/7,L-1);
}
char r[99];
char *f(int n){
  for(int L=1,B=7;1;L++,B*=7) {
    for(int i=0;i<B;i++) {
      if(V(i,L)==n){
        for(int j=0;j<L;j++) {
          r[j]="IVXLCDM"[i%7];i/=7;
        }
        r[L]=0;
        return r;
      }
    }
  }
}
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%s\n", f(atoi(argv[1])));
}
```

`V` computes the numerical value of a given roman numeral string `s` of length `L`.  Strings are encoded base 7 (first digit is s%7, second digit is s/7%7, ...).  Each digit is encoded with I=0, V=1, ..., M=6.  `f` does a brute-force enumeration of possible roman numeral strings to find one that `V` evaluates to `n`.

The total number of roman numeral digits is optimal.  The longest roman numeral needed for [-1000,3000] is 11 digits (e.g. -827=CMDDMLXXIII), which takes about 5 minutes on my machine.

Comment: Wait a moment, that doesn't behave the way specified. Your program gives e.g. `LMCLXXIII` as the answer to `-777`. I'd read that as `-50+1000-100+50+10+10+3 = 923 ≠ -777`, only with "rightmost _higher_ -valued" instead of "_highest_" does it give `-777`. But that was just what you asked for in the comments!

Comment: @leftaroundabout: of course you are right.  I'll fix it, but no time right now...

Comment: @leftaroundabout: ok, all fixed.

Comment: All right. It's _not_ optimal now, though (e.g. gives `VVVXI` for `-4` when `IXVX` is actually shorter, as I just noticed) – but that's perfectly legal.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: ok, fixed again.  Hopefully it is correct this time...

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 25637 (= 268 + 25369) <strike>26045 (= 222+25823)</strike>

```
r 0="VVX"
r n=s(zip[1000,500,100,50,10,5]"MDCLXV")n ξ
ξ='ξ'
s[]q f
 |q<0=s[](5-q)f++"V"
 |q<1=""
 |r<-q-1='I':s[]r f
s ω@((v,a):l)q f
 |q>=v,f/=a=a:s ω(q-v)ξ
 |f==a,γ<-'I':a:s l(q-v+1)ξ,η γ<η(s l q ξ)=γ
 |f==ξ,γ<-s ω(v-q)a++[a],η γ<η(s l q ξ)=γ
 |True=s l q ξ
η=length
```

to be used as e.g.

```
GHCi> r 7
"VII"
GHCi> r 39
"XIL"
GHCi> r (-39)
"ICXLC"        --  "LLXILC" in my original version
GHCi> r 1983
"MXVIIM"
GHCi> r 259876
"MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMCXXIVM"
```

You can evaluate the length sum with the straightforward

```
GHCi> sum . map(length.r) $ [-1000..3000]
25369
```

Which takes something in the order of a minute.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 25987 (= 164 + 25823)

```
h=->i,d,v,k{i==0?'':i<v ?(a=h[v-i,x=d[1..-1],v/k,k^7]+d[0];i<0?a:(b=h[i,x,v/k,k^7];a.size<b.size ? a :b)):d[0]+h[i-v,d,v,k]}
r=->i{i==0?'DDM':h[i,'MDCLXVI',1000,2]}
```

You can call `r` directly to get the results. The sum over the specified range yields

```
> (-1000..3000).map{|i|r[i].size}.reduce &:+
25823
```

which is the optimal sum as with the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 23537 (639 characters of code + 22898 characters of output)

```
class M
{
    public static string R(int n, int? s = new int?())
    {
        var r = "";
        var D = new Dictionary<int, string> {{ 1000, "M"}, { 900, "CM"},{ 800, "CCM"},{ 500, "D"}, { 400, "CD"},{ 300, "CCD"},{100, "C"}, {90, "XC"},{80, "XXC"},{50, "L"}, {40, "XL"}, {10, "X"}, {9, "IX"}, {8, "IIX"}, {5, "V"}, {4, "IV"},{1, "I"}};
        if (n == 0) return "VVX";
        if (n == -1) return "IIIIIIV";
        if (n < 0) return N(n * -1);

        foreach(int k in D.Keys)
        {
            if (s.HasValue && k > s) continue;

            while(k <= n)
            {
                n -= k; 
                r += D[k];
            }
        }

        return r;
    }

    public static string N(int n)
    {
        var D = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "I"}, {5, "V"}, {10, "X"}, {50, "L"}, {100, "C"}, { 500, "D"}, {1000, "M"}};

        int i = D.Keys.First(v => v >= n), m = D.Keys.Where(v => v < i).Max();

        return R(n + i, m) + D[i];
    }
}
```

To Calculate:

`Enumerable.Range(-1000, 3000).Sum(i => M.R(i).Length);`

Comment: And what's your score?